# Java panel alignment

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, alignment

```
class CipherGUIFrame extends JFrame {
  public CipherGUIFrame() {
    super("Caesar Cipher GUI");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 600);

    JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
    JSpinner myspinner=new JSpinner();
    JPanel mainframe = new JPanel();
    mainframe.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainframe, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cleartext"));
    p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Spinner"));
    p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ciphertext"));
    p1.add(area1);
    p2.add(myspinner);
    p3.add(area2);
    mainframe.add(p1);
    mainframe.add(p2);
    mainframe.add(p3);
    this.add(mainframe);
  }
}
```

It seems that this code produces something which looks similar to this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZIUdrBP.jpg]

I am trying to tidy this up so it looks cleaner; is there a way to shrink the middle panel or to make the others bigger to make it look nicer?

Comment: Could you show an image of just what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The middle panel is the spinner field...isn't it?

Comment: Don't set the sizes of anything, but instead set the columns and rows of your JTextAreas. Don't use BoxLayout when you don't want its behaviors. Put your JTextAreas in JScrollPanes instead. And don't forget to `pack()` your JFrame.

Comment: And use `JTextArea(int, int)` to provide sizing hints for the components

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the sizes of anything, but instead set the columns and rows of your JTextAreas. Don't use BoxLayout when you don't want its behaviors. Put your JTextAreas in JScrollPanes instead. And don't forget to pack() your JFrame.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cipher2 extends JPanel {
   public static final int ROWS = 12;
   public static final int COLS = 30;

   private JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
   private JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);

   public Cipher2() {
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  // Box OK here

      JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea1);
      add(wrapComponentWithTitle(scroll1, "Fubar"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

      add(wrapComponentWithTitle(new JSpinner(), "Spinner"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
      add(wrapComponentWithTitle(scroll1, "Snafu"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private JPanel wrapComponentWithTitle(JComponent component, String title) {
      // BoxLayout NOT OK here. Use BorderLayout instead
      JPanel wrapPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      wrapPanel.add(component);
      wrapPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
      return wrapPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Cipher2 mainPanel = new Cipher2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: well how do i expand them to make them as wide as the window?

Comment: @HuangLee: by using the correct layout managers. A BorderLayout will fill any component added to its CENTER position. Read up on and learn how the layout managers function to understand what they can do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer: change Y_AXIS to X_AXIS.

<3